# [Wordpress][Nextgen Gallery] How reorder admin menu position

Tags: wordpress, submenu, nextgen-gallery

Is it possible to move Nextgen Gallery icon under Media in Admin Menu?

I know how to reorder Admin menu items:

```
function new_menu_order($new_order) {
    if (!$new_order) return true;
        return array(
        'index.php',
        'edit.php',
        'edit.php?post_type=page',
    'upload.php', //Media icon
    'admin.php?page=nextgen-gallery', // Nextgen Gallery link
    'edit.php?post_type=slide'
      );
}
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'new_menu_order');
add_filter('menu_order', 'new_menu_order');
```

But adding "admin.php?page=nextgen-gallery" in this code doesn't help. Gallery is still  last position.

Comment: It might be due to priority. Can you please try by adding the lowest priority

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a kind of solution: I had to edit admin.php in plugin admin folder using a [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Answer (score 0):

It seems due to the priority

Have you tried by setting lower priority to the filters? You can try by settings priority as 99999 as below.

```
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'new_menu_order', 99999);
add_filter('menu_order', 'new_menu_order', 99999);
```